# An inequality for positive definite matrices

Tags: pr.probability, matrices, inequalities

Let $K$ and $K^\prime$ positive definite $n \times n$ matrices, such that for all vectors $f \ge 0$ with **nonnegative** coordinates we have

$$\sum_{i,j} K_{ij} f_i f_j \le \sum_{ij} K^\prime_{ij} f_i f_j$$

Can someone prove the following inequality?

$$ \sum_{i,j} \exp K_{ij} \le \sum_{i,j} \exp K^\prime_{ij} $$

The reason why I believe it is true is that I have a proof using Slepian-Kahane-type comparison for Wick exponentials of Gaussian random vectors with covariance $K$ and $K^\prime$, which might look like a perverse way of doing something as simple-looking as this. Ideally, I'd like to see a more straightforward proof, or maybe some general suggestions on how to use that weird positivity condition on $K^\prime - K$.

**Upd:** The "weird positivity condition" is nothing but dual to something known by the name ["complete positivity"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompletelyPositiveMatrix.html).

Comment: This one essentially follows because for positive definite matrices $K, K'$ such that $K \preceq K'$, it follows that $K \circ K \preceq K' \circ K'$, where $\circ$ denotes the Schur (Hadamard) product.

Comment: @Suvrit: Actually, I don't see how to show even that unless the difference $K^\prime - K$ is positive definite.

Comment: Ah, your first inequality has an extra *nonnegativity* hypothesis, which (despite its being **bold**), I missed seeing...

Comment: @Suvrit: That's the whole point. :)

Comment: The dual to the completely positive cone is called the "copositive cone", i.e. your assumption is that $K'-K$ be copositive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple proof (thanks to the OP for a proof that the Hadamard exponential is CP).

I'll write $K$ and $H \equiv K'$ to keep the notation simpler.

As $K \succeq 0$, it follows that its Schur exponent $[e^{k_{ij}}]$ is also psd. Thus, in particular, we can write the following factorization:
\begin{equation*}
 [e^{k_{ij}}] = \sum\nolimits_l u_l u_l^T.
\end{equation*}

> **Theorem.** The Schur-Hadamard exponential $[e^{k_{ij}}]$ is [completely positive](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompletelyPositiveMatrix.html), i.e., in the above factorization we can select the vectors $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ to be elementwise nonnegative.

In addition to the OP's elegant argument (see comments below), another proof to this theorem may also be found as Theorem 2.30 (pp 131) in [Completely Positive Matrices](http://books.google.com/books?id=AllToPtYGGgC&lpg=PP1&dq=completely%20positive&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=2.30&f=false), by Berman and ‎Shaked-Monderer.

Then, consider
\begin{equation*}
 \sum\nolimits_{ij} e^{k_{ij}}(h_{ij}-k_{ij}) = \mbox{tr}[(H-K)\sum\nolimits_l u_lu_l^T] = \sum\nolimits_l u_l^T (H-K)u_l \ge 0,
\end{equation*}
where the final inequality follows from our hypothesis since $u_l \ge 0$.

Since $\exp(x)$ is a convex function, we have
\begin{equation*}
 e^h \ge e^k + e^k(h-k),\qquad\forall h, k.
\end{equation*}
Thus, it follows that
\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{ij} e^{h_{ij}} \ge \sum_{ij} e^{k_{ij}} + \sum_{ij} e^{k_{ij}}(h_{ij}-k_{ij}).
\end{equation*}
But the above argumentation showed that the last term on the rhs is nonnegative.$\qquad\blacksquare$

Comment: Actually, it is true that $\exp K$ is completely positive for every positive definite $K$. And guess what, this has a probabilistic reason:  $\exp K_{ij} = \mathsf{E} \exp[X_i - \frac{1}{2} K_{ii}] \exp[X_j - \frac{1}{2} K_{jj}]$, where $X$ is the Gaussian with covariance $K$.

Comment: So if exp is CP, we are done!

Comment: I find your proof of CP of exp much nicer than using a bruteforce argument based on decomposing $K=\sum_l v_lv_l^T$, etc.

Comment: Actually, my original motivation was to avoid Gaussian tricks - and instead we arrived at special properties of exponential...